# How to run 2 functions if we have 2 forms on the page?

Tags: php

Not a php `guru` here.

I have one `form` and when I hit the `submit`, it runs the `function()`:

```
<form id="saveId" action="" method="POST" class="" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="hidden" name="save_post_value" value="<?php echo $userPosts; ?>"> 
    <button  type="submit" class="save_post btn btn-danger">Save to box</button>
</form>

<?php                       
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST") {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'save_post', $userPosts );
    }
?>
```

That's fine with one form, but what if we have two forms and functions?

```
<form id="saveId" action="" method="POST" class="" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="hidden" name="save_post_value" value="<?php echo $userPosts; ?>"> 
    <button  type="submit" class="save_post btn btn-danger">Save to box</button>
</form>

<form id="favorite" action="" method="POST" class="" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="hidden" name="save_fav" value="<?php echo $userfavs; ?>"> 
    <button  type="submit" class="save_fav btn btn-danger">Add to favs</button>
</form>
```

Can't do obviously:

```
<?php                       
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST") {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'save_post', $_POST['save_post_value'] );
    }                   
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST") {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'save_fav', $_POST['save_fav'] );
    }
?>
```

Comment: Just test and use like `if isset($_POST['save_post_value']){ /* First form */  } else { /* Second form*// } `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check which hidden input is set.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    if (isset($_POST['save_post_value'])) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'save_post', $_POST['save_post_value'] );
    } elseif (isset($_POST['save_fav'])) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'save_fav', $_POST['save_fav'] );
    }
}
```

Comment: ok i see, so let me ask you a lame question if I might, with `isset(..` we are checking if the submit button of the current form containing that hidden field, submitted the values of that hidden field? I may have over complicated the way I've asked. Ha!

Comment: Yes, that's what we're checking.

Comment: gives an error tho `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'elseif' (T_ELSEIF) in`, needs a `}` Edited your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Either use different action URLs, use a name and value on the submit button, or use a hidden field.

An example of button name and value:

```
<button type="submit" name="action" value="save_fav">Add to Favs</button>
```

...

```
if ($_POST['action'] === 'save_fav') { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="saveId" action="" method="POST" class="" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="hidden" id="save_post" value="save_post|<?php echo $userPosts; ?>"> 
    <button  type="submit" class="save_post btn btn-danger">Save to box</button>
</form>

<form id="favorite" action="" method="POST" class="" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="hidden" id="save_post" value="save_fav|<?php echo $userfavs; ?>"> 
    <button  type="submit" class="save_fav btn btn-danger">Add to favs</button>
</form>

<?php                       
   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST"){
       list($type, $value) = explode("|", $_POST['save_post']) ;
       update_user_meta( $user_id, $type, $value);
   }
?>
```

See if it works or not.

Comment: it won't work at all, you're sending both variables to the same function `update_user_meta( $user_id, $type, $value);` while they are two

Comment: Did you run it at least once and check the database ?